# jest fails with error: Cannot find module 'jose-node-cjs-runtime/jwt/sign'

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, superagent, jose

I am testing my Node.js API using jest. This API is an Express app used for managing tasks. It has signup/login feature to allow only authenticated users to use the app. It has an endpoint for signing up new user and many endpoints are present which uses an express middleware to validate the user authentication through JWT. I have `jose-node-cjs-runtime@^3.15.5` package installed which is used for JWT generation and validation.

If I run the project using `dev` script `env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js`, there are no issues and it runs fine. I am trying to test user signup using jest test file which uses `superagent` package to test the endpoint. I am using test script `env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch` to run the test. This command is showing following error and test is failing:

```
 FAIL  tests/user.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'jose-node-cjs-runtime/jwt/sign' from 'src/models/user.js'

    Require stack:
      src/models/user.js
      src/routers/user.js
      src/app.js
      tests/user.test.js

      3 | const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
      4 | // library for signing jwt
    > 5 | const { SignJWT } = require('jose-node-cjs-runtime/jwt/sign');
        |                     ^
      6 | // library for generating symmetric key for jwt
      7 | const { createSecretKey } = require('crypto');
      8 | // task model

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:313:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/user.js:5:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.385 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

I am unable to figure out why this error is caused. Please help me in finding the solution.

I was using Node.js version 16.7.0 and got this error. I have upgraded my Node.js version today. My current Node.js version is 16.9.0. After upgrading Node.js version also I am receiving this error. Following is the package.json file contents for the project:

```json
{
  "name": "task-manager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.6",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jose-node-cjs-runtime": "^3.15.5",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "sharp": "^0.29.0",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6"
  }
}
```

Following is the contents of `src/models/user.js`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
// library for signing jwt
const { SignJWT } = require('jose-node-cjs-runtime/jwt/sign');
// library for generating symmetric key for jwt
const { createSecretKey } = require('crypto');
// task model
const Task = require('./task');
...
```

Content of `src/tests/user.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../src/app');

describe('user route', () => {
  test('should signup a new user', async () => {
    await request(app)
      .post('/users')
      .send({
        name: '__test_name__',
        email: '__test_email__',
        password: '__test_password__',
      })
      .expect(201);
  });
});
```

Comment: could you post your both `./config/dev.env` and  './config/test.env' files for reference

Comment: @Sohan, I don't think environment files are the issue here. I have run `jest --watch` (instead of `env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch`) and also received the same error. Also the config files contains secrets so I do not want to post them.

Comment: I think you are missing configuration of jest, which tell from where to pick module dicrectories and src files?

Comment: What is the `"<rootDir>"` you have added ? should That follow  some path
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#rootdir-string

Comment: I have no need to change this. So I have provided default value which will revert to my current working directory. In the docs same is mentioned https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#rootdir-string: Note that using '<rootDir>' as a string token in any other path-based config settings will refer back to this value.

Comment: I have found that `require('jose-node-cjs-runtime/jwt/sign');` this import is causing the issue. If I comment this line and its related code ( do and same for other `jose` imports), then test runs successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237079/discussion-between-nlern-and-sohan).

Comment: I have raised a bug in jest github repo: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11872. The bug was closed with comment that jest does not yet support `exports` which is used by the package `jose-node-cjs-runtime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the resolver from [this workaround](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771#issuecomment-841624042).

I have a test repo with `jose` being used in all kinds of tools [here](https://github.com/panva/it-should-just-work).

Obviously your setup may vary if you use ts-jest, or ESM test files, or similar. But at that point you should be familiar with the different jest magical options.

```
> jest --resolver='./temporary_resolver.js' 'jest.test.*'

 PASS  ./jest.test.js
  ✓ it works in .js (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.367 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /jest.test.*/i.
```

```js
// temporary workaround while we wait for https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771

const resolver = require('enhanced-resolve').create.sync({
  conditionNames: ['require'],
  extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.node', '.ts']
})

module.exports = function (request, options) {
  return resolver(options.basedir, request)
}
```

```
const { generateSecret } = require("jose/util/generate_secret");

test('it works in .js', async () => {
  expect(typeof generateSecret).toBe('function');
  expect(await generateSecret('HS256')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Bottom line - its about making jest require the cjs distribution of the jose module and using the exports mapping. Note that ESM is still not natively supported and neither is the exports mapping, both of which are stable for over a year in all LTS releases of node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution is a bit lengthy as a third part package needs to be installed then a new resolver file needs to be created. However this solution seems to be more cleaner than hard coding the import paths.

Answer (score 2):

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11872) in jest github repo. The issue was closed with comments:

> The module [uses exports](https://www.runpkg.com/?jose-node-cjs-runtime@3.17.0/package.json#44) which isn't supported yet: [#9771](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771)

So I read through the comments already logged on similar issue and found [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10422#issuecomment-830257504) helpful comment which can be used as a work around until jest natively supports this feature.

I found that the `jose-node-cjs-runtime` module `exports` field is like following:

```json
"./jwt/sign": "./dist/node/cjs/jwt/sign.js",
"./jwt/verify": "./dist/node/cjs/jwt/verify.js",
```

So I updated the `jest` config in `package.json` as follows:

```json
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^jose-node-cjs-runtime/(.*)$": "jose-node-cjs-runtime/dist/node/cjs/$1"
  }
}
```

After that running the test I did not face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the configuration of jest and it can be found  [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)

Mainly look for [moduleirectories](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#moduledirectories-arraystring),
You can add both relative and absolute paths.

Make sure to include  in the roots array,  in the modulePaths array, and node_modules in the moduleDirectories array, unless you've got a good reason to exclude them.
Here is the sample of jest config, you can include this in `package.json` file

```
 "jest": {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>",
    "/homeDir/yourLocalDir/path/"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>",
    "/homeDir/yourLocalDir/otherDir/path"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!MODULE_NAME_HERE).+\\.js$"]
}
```

Comment: I have added these configurations in `pakcage.json` jest config section but still getting the same error.

Comment: Update your question with jest config you added, let me check that

Comment: I have updated the question with jest config.

Comment: What happens when you change this line `const app = require('../src/app');` to this `const app = require('app');`
And Add `src` to your 
`"moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
  "src"
  ],`

Comment: Now I am getting following error: Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Comment: Try adding following to jest
`transformIgnorePatterns: [ "/node_modules/(?!MODULE_NAME_HERE).+\\.js$"],`

Replace `MODULE_NAME_HERE` with Your JWT module

Comment: I have raised a bug in jest github repo: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11872. The bug was closed with comment that jest does not yet support `exports` which is used by the package `jose-node-cjs-runtime`.